# Elastic Search sorting very slow on large datasets

Tags: elasticsearch

The sorting of data in ES was very fast when I had less data, but when the data increased into GBs then the sorting of the fields is very very slow, normal fields < 1 sec, but for the fields with the below mapping the sorting time is > 10 seconds and sometimes more.

I am unable to figure out why is that? can anyone help me with this?

Mapping:

```
"newFields": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "group": { "type": "keyword" },
      "fieldType": { "type": "keyword" },
      "name": { "type": "keyword" },
      "stringValue": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "normalizer": "sort_normalizer"
          }
        }
      },
      "longValue": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "doubleValue": {
        "type": "float"
      },
      "booleanValue": {
        "type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  }
```

Query:

```
 {
  "index": "transactions-read",
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "bool": { "filter": { "bool": { "must": [{ "match_all": {} }] } } }
    },
    "sort": [
      {
        "newFields.intValue": {
          "order": "desc",
          "nested": {
            "path": "newFields",
            "filter": { "match": { "newFields.name": "johndoe" } }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50
}
```

So is there any way to make it faster? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: What nested field are you sorting by? `/* my nested path */` is not really helpful

Comment: @joe, i have updated it.

Comment: What is the size of the index, and  how much it can grow in future

Comment: @gaurav9620,  I have more than 100 million documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested datatype is known for bad performance and on top of it you are using sort which is again a costly operation Please refer this great [medium blog of Gojek engineering team on their perf issues with nested docs](https://blog.gojekengineering.com/elasticsearch-the-trouble-with-nested-documents-e97b33b46194).

They suggested some optimization which includes changing the schema as well but they have not covered the infra level optimization like tunning the JVM heap size and having the favourable shards and replicas which are backbones of elasticsearch and its worth checking and tunning these infra params as well.

Answer (score 0):

Nested sort will be slower compared to non-nested sort. As the number of nested documents in your index increases - unfortunately, sort will slow down.

Comment: Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Comment: Avoiding nested fields will be one option. But since it depends on your requirements..I'm not sure of other options .

Answer (score 0):

If you want a faster sorting result, one of the options is defining index sorting. It's like configuring a default behaviour.
The only disadvantage is you have to modify your index sorting if you want to change the behaviour.

Below is an example how to define index sorting :

```
PUT testindex
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "sort.field": [ "username", "date" ], 
      "sort.order": [ "asc", "desc" ]       
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "username": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "doc_values": true
      },
      "date": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-index-sorting.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34467949)